# Write-read conflicts in Linux C++ IO concurrency

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, fork, stdthread

Considering the writing of an online evaluation system, each `JudgeTask` has an independent input file path, output file path, expected file path, pending program path, and corresponding evaluation results.
For each JudgeTask, a thread is started with std::async, and each thread completes:

1. run: Use fork to create a child process, redirect the input with a pipe in the process, and redirect the output to the specified file
2. test: Read the expected file and output the file comparison
3. The result is returned.

The problem occurs in the test phase: test is on the same thread as run, that is, it waits for run to write before it is read. test opens the file, `feof`, `ferror` are okay, but when you call fgetc to read, the corresponding file stream still has data but returns `EOF`: this happens completely randomly. Even if you use `fsync/flock`, it won't help.

I used the following code to add threads：
(**NOTE** I've removed a lot of the error handling code, and you can assume that all the pointers point to legitimate data)

```
std::future<std::unique_ptr<JudgeResult>> makeJudgeTask(
    JudgeTask *task, const BasicCodeRunner *runner, const std::function<DiffResult(FILE *, FILE *)> &streamComparer) {
    return std::async(std::launch::async, [task, runner, streamComparer]() {
        runJudgeTask(task, runner);
        testJudgeTask(task, streamComparer);
        return std::move(task->_result);
    });
}
```

And the following code runs the program and completes the redirecting input and output:

```
void runJudgeTask(JudgeTask *task, const BasicCodeRunner *runner) {
    if (task->executed()) {
        return;
    }
    auto runResult 
        = runner->runOnFile(task->_testProgramName, task->_inputFilePath, task->_outputFilePath);
    task->_hasExecuted = true;
    if (runResult.exitCode != 0) {
        task->_result = /* make error result */
        return;
    }
    task->_result = std::make_unique<JudgeResult>(
        task->_inputFilePath.stem(), ProgramExecutionStatus::RUNNING, runResult.resourceUsage);
}

RunCodeCaseResult LinuxCodeRunner::runOnFile(const fs::path &programPath,
                                             const fs::path &inputPath,
                                             const fs::path &outputPath) const {
    int inputFd = open(inputPath.c_str(), O_RDONLY);
    int outputFd = open(outputPath.c_str(), O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    if (inputFd == -1 || outputFd == -1) {
         // error
    }
    auto [status, runtime, memory] = _runFork(inputFd, outputFd, programPath.c_str());
    close(inputFd);
    fsync(outputFd);
    close(outputFd);
    if (status == -1) {
        std::exit(errno);
    } else if (status != 0) {
        MyLogger.debug("program {} exited with status {}", programPath.u8string(), status);
    }
    return {inputPath.stem().u8string(), outputPath, status, runtime, memory};
}

std::tuple<int, long, long> 
LinuxCodeRunner::_runFork(int inputFd, int outputFd, const char *programPath) noexcept {
    using namespace std::literals;
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        return std::make_tuple(-1, 0, 0);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        dup2(inputFd, STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(outputFd, STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2(outputFd, STDERR_FILENO);
        execl(programPath, programPath, nullptr);
        exit(0);
    } else {
        int status;
        rusage usage {};
        wait3(&status, 0, &usage);
        // return info
    }
}
```

test and run are under the same thread. And test is simply waiting for the run to finish and then using fgetc to compare the data character by character.

```
void testJudgeTask(JudgeTask *task, const std::function<DiffResult(FILE *, FILE *)> &streamComparer) {
    while (!task->_hasExecuted) std::this_thread::yield();
    if (task->_result->status != ProgramExecutionStatus::RUNNING) {
        return;
    }
    FILE *expectedFileStream = fopen(task->_expectedFilePath.c_str(), "r");
    FILE *outputFileStream = fopen(task->_outputFilePath.c_str(), "r+");
    // error handled.
    auto [expected, output, tokenCount] = streamComparer(outputFileStream, expectedFileStream);
    if (expected.empty() && output.empty()) {
        task->_result->status = ProgramExecutionStatus::ACCEPTED;
    } else {
        task->_result->status = ProgramExecutionStatus::WRONG_ANSWER;
        task->_result->detail = DiffResult {expected, output, tokenCount};

    }
}
```

streamComparer is just a simple loop, checked character by character via fgetc, all the way to EOF.

Even though there is data in the file stream, `fgetc` returns an `EOF` as soon as it is called, why does this happen?

Comment: I think you have a race condition somewhere. Can you provide a [mcve], so people here can reproduce the issue themselves?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Hello, Thanks for your answer, I uploaded the  minimal reproducible example to Github: the code has been simplified, but the problem still exists, and you can find out what's wrong with it after running it a few times... 
https://github.com/himuhuan/JudgeTestBugReproducible

Comment: A few points on that: Firstly, put the [mcve] inline into your question instead of linking an external, volatile resource. Your Q should be self-contained. Then, looking at the code, there is zero synchronization between the threads. It also isn't necessary here, because no data is shared. The `hasExecuted` flag is useless, as is waiting for it to be set. If you want to run the two functions in separate threads in the future, you'd make the mistake of first signaling you are done before even starting the work.

Comment: You could try compiling your code with `-fsanitize=thread` (and `-g` or similar for debug symbols). That will slow down your execution a bit (sometimes a lot), but it will provide useful feedback when it comes to multi-threading issues.